# presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() not working properly

Tags: swiftui

I'm using the sheet method to display a simple form and I pass into it a couple of varsiables. The problem is that if I click the button which performs the .dismiss() method after changing the variables passed in it doesn't work. Instead if I directly click the button it works normally.
Here's the code:

```
struct EditProductForm: View {

    var listIndex : Int
    var product : Product

    @State var quantity: Int
    @State var productName : String

    @EnvironmentObject var data : Data
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationModeEdit

    func editProduct(){
        self.data.editProduct(listIndex: self.listIndex, product: self.product, productName: self.productName, quantity: self.quantity)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            Spacer()

            VStack(spacing: 64){

                Text("Edit Product")

                TextField("Edit the name", text: $productName)

                Picker(selection: $quantity, label: Text("Quantity")){
                    Text("OK").tag(Constants.Status.OK)
                    Text("Almost finished").tag(Constants.Status.ALMOST_NONE)
                    Text("Finished").tag(Constants.Status.NONE)
                }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

                Button(action: {
                    self.editProduct()
                    self.presentationModeEdit.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }){
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }

            Spacer()
        }.padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

I also checked if the isPresented variable changes value and it's actually toggled when i click the button but the sheet stays there.

Here's the code where I use the form:

```
ForEach(self.list.content, id: \.self) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.show_modal_edit[self.list.content.firstIndex(of: item)!] = true
                        }){
                            ProductCell(item: item)
                        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$show_modal_edit[self.list.content.firstIndex(of: item)!]){
                            EditProductForm(
                                listIndex: self.listIndex,
                                product: item,
                                quantity: item.quantity,
                                productName: item.productName
                            ).environmentObject(self.data)
                        }
                    }
```

show_modal_edit is a list of Bool, I checked the values and apparently the correct one is passed to the isPresented field of .sheet().

Answer (score 0):

I've setup the following test version of your code and all is working well for me on ios 13.4 and macos catalyst after renaming Data to Datax.

This points to the function in editProduct()

```
        self.data.editProduct(listIndex: self.listIndex, product: self.product, productName: self.productName, quantity: self.quantity)
```

as the possible source of your problem. Specifically, using Data as the name for your type. It seems to clash with the system struct Data type. Try renaming your ObservableObject class to something else (Datax in my test).

```
import SwiftUI

class Datax: ObservableObject {
@Published var xxx = "xxx"

func editProduct(listIndex: Int, product: String, productName: String, quantity: Int) {
    print("---> editProduct")
}
}

struct ContentView: View {
var data = Datax()
@State var showEditProductForm = false
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("main view")
        Button("EditProductForm") {
            self.showEditProductForm.toggle()
        }
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showEditProductForm) {
        EditProductForm(listIndex: 2, product: "product", quantity: 1, productName: "productName")
            .environmentObject(self.data)
    }
}
}

struct EditProductForm: View {

@EnvironmentObject var data: Datax
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationModeEdit: Binding<PresentationMode>

var listIndex: Int
var product: String
@State var quantity: Int
@State var productName: String

func editProduct() {
    self.data.editProduct(listIndex: self.listIndex, product: self.product, productName: self.productName, quantity: self.quantity)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Spacer()
        VStack(spacing: 64){
            Text("Edit Product")
            TextField("Edit the name", text: $productName)
            Picker(selection: $quantity, label: Text("Quantity")){
                Text("OK").tag(0)
                Text("Almost finished").tag(1)
                Text("Finished").tag(2)
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Button(action: {
                self.editProduct()
                self.presentationModeEdit.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }){
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }.padding(.horizontal)
}
}
```

Hope this helps track down your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately that didn't work for me. I doubt that the cause could be the editPorduct method since in a different file I call a similar method but the dismiss works. Maybe it has to do with the fact that my "EditProductForm" is inside a ForEach. I added the code where i call it in my question.